# Trying to Dynamically change buttons in Jswing

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to change the amount of `JButtons` in a `JPanel` based on the about of string in a certain set. The Maps and Sets are just from a library from my uni. I don't get any errors in my panel when I run this but I don't see the `JButtons` updated in the GUI. The `JPanel` is contained in a `JScrollPane` in the view but I don't think that that should matter.

Is there something that I am missing around how Jswing handles the panels or layout?

I know that the size thing is a bit of a mess but works.

```java
public void updateServerDisplay(Set<String> serverSet) {

        this.ROWS_OF_SERVER = serverSet.size();
        int size = this.ROWS_OF_SERVER;

        //create a copy of the set
        Set<String> setCopy = serverSet.newInstance();
        setCopy.transferFrom(serverSet);

        //get ready to start over
        this.serverPanel.removeAll();
        //reset the layout
        this.serverPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.ROWS_OF_SERVER, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            //just to make sure the number of files is correct.
            System.out.println("button - make" + i);

            //assign the string to a JButton
            String current = setCopy.removeAny();
            this.serverFiles[i] = new JButton(current);
            //register listener
            this.serverFiles[i].addActionListener(this);

            //Add to the panel
            this.serverPanel.add(this.serverFiles[i]);

            //add to the map for later
            this.serverMap.add(current, this.serverFiles[i]);
            //add back to the set
            serverSet.add(current);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok, just you miss to call a "fire" command. You added the object references, call a `repaint()` and a `validate()` method on the container, it should works.

Sorry for my english :/